# Pygame window freezes sometimes

Tags: python, pygame

I created A star algorithm visualization in pygame, and pygame window freezes sometimes (when algorithm is working), I know that this algorithm is not the most optimized one, but I think that the algorithm isnt causing this issue. Please help me, because its quite annoying, and i dont know what causes this issue. 
Link to code -> https://github.com/DeathEyeXD/PythonProjects/blob/master/aStarVisualization.py

Answer (score 0):

Please paste relevant part of the code here and show us what you have tried so far.

I assume that you have a main pygame loop running at a certain frequency. When you have a function calculating things in the main loop that takes a considerable amount of time, it will cause the game window to freeze. This is because it cannot reach other things (like your event function) at the same time as it is calculating the path.

With A* algorithm you can make it nicer by drawing the progress (draw the neighbors and checked cells for example). I did a project like this previously which works nicely. You then call your draw function within the A* function at relevant places and you won't get the freeze issue.

Comment: That's what I did, I mean that program is also a A* visualizer, but when drawing the process of finding the path, window sometimes freezes, and skips some frames.

Comment: I see. Have you tried playing around with the pygame clock to see if you can lower the frames per seconds?

Comment: Yes I tried, and clock freezes this window even more often unless its set to 10 ticks (which is too slow :/ ). I don't know what is going on there...